# JQuery intercept click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script

```
$('#addDescriptionButtonId').click(function(){
        alert ('ee');           
    });
```

and this button

```
<button id="addDescriptionButtonId" class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">Add Description</button>
```

expecting the alert when I click, but nothing happens when I click

Comment: Are you sure you're adding jQuery to the page? Your code is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your script is either running in `$(document).ready()` or is at the end of your `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `jQuery` library

```js
$('#addDescriptionButtonId').click(function(){
        alert ('ee');
        $('#productFormId').attr('method', 'post');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addDescriptionButtonId" class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">Add Description</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, If your expecting not to add any JQuery library and want the alert to work on button click then you might want to use native JS click events on button as shown below.

Javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('addDescriptionButtonId');
element.onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
   alert("ee");
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="addDescriptionButtonId" class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">Add Description</button>
```

Hope this helps you.